# What is the strength of unpadded RSA?

Tags: encryption, rsa, public-key, homomorphic-encryption

I would like to use [unpadded RSA for homomorphic encryption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homomorphic_encryption#Unpadded_RSA) in a toy P2P game, for things like fair coin flips and shuffling.

How many bits of security does unpadded RSA have, in relation to its key size?

Comment: I don't think you are asking the right question. It isn't the "bits of security" I would be worried about, it is the lack of [semantic security](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_security) of unpadded RSA that would concern me. So, if you need a multiplicatively homomorphic cryptosystem, I'd say, stick with [ElGamal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ElGamal_encryption).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**None**.

When enciphering any small set of values (including a fair coin flip, a byte, even a small password..), unpadded RSA (or RSA with any padding that does not include randomness) is a terminally weak encryption method: the adversary can enumerate the possible plaintext values, encrypt them using the *public* key, and check against the ciphertext to determine if the candidate plaintext value being enumerated is the right one.